# MakeBoxes for Power not matching when inside Times?

Tags: pattern-matching, boxes

If I try to define boxes for `Power[x,-1]` like this,

```
MakeBoxes[Power[x, -1], TraditionalForm] := "matched";
```

it works as long as the coefficient is 1:

```
1/x // TraditionalForm
```

> $\text{matched}$

But, for other coefficients it doesn't work, for example:

```
2/x // TraditionalForm
```

> $\frac{2}{x}$

But why?  After all, `FullForm[2/x]` returns `Times[2,Power[x,-1]]`, which *does* contain `Power[x,-1]` for which the `MakeBoxes` definition was given.  But why doesn't it work?

What is the proper way to define boxes for such expressions?

Comment: For `TraditionalForm[2/x]`, I expected "$2\,\text{matched}$" as the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by Mr. Wizard's answers, here is another possibility:

```
MakeBoxes[c_. x_Power, TraditionalForm] := MakeBoxes[c "matched"]
```

Comment: Very nice addition. :-)

Answer (score 8):

I believe the existing rules for `Times` take precedence.  (i.e. act first.)

Perhaps a derivative of this can work for you:

```
MakeBoxes[x_ /; ! FreeQ[Unevaluated@x, Power], TraditionalForm] := 
  ToBoxes[Unevaluated[x] /. _Power -> "matched"];
```

---

Responding to your entirely valid performance concern please test these for comparison:

```
MakeBoxes[x_Times /; ! FreeQ[Unevaluated@x, Power], TraditionalForm] := 
  ToBoxes[Unevaluated[x] /. _Power -> "matched"];
```

Or:

```
MakeBoxes[a___ * x_Power * b___, TraditionalForm] := MakeBoxes[a * "matched" * b]
```

Comment: Thanks.  But your suggestion looks grotesquely inefficient.  Would you know how to get it to work without using a `Conditional` on a "blanket" pattern?

Comment: @QuantumDot please see the update.

Comment: Thanks.  Since `Attributes[Times] = {Orderless, (*...*)}`, you could simplify the lhs of your last example to `MakeBoxes[a___ * x_Power, TraditionalForm] := (*...*)`, no?